Как лучше организовать архитектуру проекта в Unity?
Я сейчас делаю один проект на Unity. Вкратце, это игра про космос, где игрок управляет планетой, которая "вращается" вокруг своей звезды и защищает её от разных опасностей.
У меня в проекте есть абстрактный класс AbstractMovementSystem, от которого наследуются классы PlanetMovementSystem и MoveToTargetSystem. Сделано это потому, что в вышеуказанных классах всё равно был бы метод Move и поля _maxSpeed и _currentSpeed, а создание абстрактного класса позволяет соблюдать принцип DRY.
Эти классы ответственны исключительно за то, чтобы "передвинуть" объект на новую позицию. При этом вычисление этой новой позиции происходит в классах PlanetMovementCalc и MoveToTargetCalc, которые реализуют интерфейс IMoveCalculator. И вот на этом месте начинаются проблемы:
Для расчёта новой позиции MoveToTargetCalc нужны два вектора и скорость, а PlanetMovementCalc — input в виде значения типа float, радиус орбиты и скорость. Как вы понимаете, если я добавлю оба метода для расчёта новой позиции в IMoveCalculator, то мне придётся реализовать метод, предназначенный для MoveToTargetCalc, в PlanetMovementCalc и наоборот. Что PlanetMovementCalc, что MoveToTargetCalc — это, понятное дело, не нужно. Если реализовать методы пустыми, то это будет нарушением принципа Лисков, а если реализовать методы по-нормальному, то это будет просто куча лишнего кода, который не будет использоваться.
Вопрос: что же делать? Вообще убрать интерфейс из проекта, так как PlanetMovementCalc и MoveToTargetCalc по задумке и не должны быть взаимозаменяемыми? Или есть смысл в использовании интерфейсов? Если да, то как их использовать правильно?
(Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, просто у меня мало опыта, и сам я "докумекать" не могу)

Забить на интерфейс и просто использовать в нужном классе движения нужный класс рассчёта. И не загоняться.

Можете попробовать задать свой вопрос в сообществах Game Development и/или Code Review, думаю там вам дадут более развёрнутый ответ по вашему вопросу. Только они англоязычные...

Спасибо за ответы! Принял решение всё-таки убрать интерфейс.

Архитектура, как не странно начинается с нейминга! Если твоя архитектура начинается к класса GameManager, любой скажет, что твоя архитектура ShinimaHuina, даже не уточняя, чем именно этот класс занимается.
abstract, private, public и т.д. это модификаторы доступа, а не члены имён! Manager или System это слова паразиты в 99% случаях, когда человек не может сформулировать, чем именно сущность занимается. Аббревиатуры абсолютное зло, но сокращения допустимы, как общепринятые в конкретных областях, как например Str, Agi и Int в видеоиграх, хотя когда в один случаях слово сокращают, а в других нет, это грязь и беспорядок.

Кроме того, что у AbstractMovementSystem есть два поля, ты ни слова не написал, о его бизнес процессах. Почему называется AbstractMovementSystem? Потому, что абстрактное хрен знает что, но что-то связанное с движением! Если разные сущности объединены только именами свойств и методов, то это их объединяет общий интерфейс, потому что никакой логики они не наследуют, как юнит и разрушаемая декорация, которые оба IDamagable, но получаемый урон, каждый обрабатывает по своему. По двум свойствам Speed и MaxSpeed, можно разве что выделить интерфейс ISpeed, хотя дико странно, что планеты у тебя двигаются с переменной скоростью и имеют потолок скорости.
В этих случаях, я честно именовал класс аля... XXX и уже реализовав нужный мне функционал, давал имя отражающее этот функционал в контексте названий методов или разделял сущность на несколько в виду множественной ответственности.

Я не особо понял, зачем логика движения выделена в классы, почему движение планеты описано не к кассе планеты? В некоторых случаях мы выносим логику из классов, как например в паттерне State, потому что оно меняется, но тут это зачем?
Если бы все тела в твоей солнечной системе двигались согласно Ньютоновской механике, был бы класс типа CelestialBody, от которого наследовались все объекты и обработкой этих тел занимался бы какой-нибудь NewtonPhysics. У тебя это не так, реальная физика игре не нужна, звезда не двигается, планеты перемещаются строго по кругу а корабли летят куда хотят, у них буквально нет ни хрена общего между собой.

Твоя проблема не в интерфейсах и вообще не в абстракции, а в том, что ты не можешь сформулировать, чё те надо то... и чё делать то... и просто бежишь впереди паровоза, что бы бежать и не думать, потому что думать это больно!

Спасибо за разнос! Отдельное спасибо за советы по неймингу — буду пользоваться. По поводу _speed и _maxSpeed: это protected поля, а не свойства, именно поэтому и используется абстрактный класс. Про бизнес-процессы я не писал не потому, что их нет, а потому, что не посчитал это важным для решения проблемы. То, что скорость планеты может меняться, — это не странно, просто сама игра в жанре аркада, поэтому скорость не является константой и может меняться. Предпоследняя часть — это как раз то, о чём я спрашивал вчера: нужна ли вообще здесь абстракция . Спасибо за ответ, хоть и жёсткий.

Но вообще — всё по фактам, ещё раз большое спасибо!

Приватные поля это самое последнее о чем есть смысл рассказывать, они всего лишь данные для бизнес логики. По именам понятно, что это поля, но при использовании интерфейка, это были бы свойства.

Ответ кстати не жёсткий. В программировании всё просто, либо ты критичен к коду и развиваешься, либо без конца жрёшь последствия говнокодинга. Ты не уникален, проблемы с которыми ты сталкиваешься, сталкиваются все. Критикуя код кого-то, я зачастую критикую себя прошлого. Это норма.
